# Another load bearing wall question

Tags: load-bearing, renovation, demolition

First, yes, I will consult an engineer before removing any walls. I mostly just need a gut check to determine if it’s even worth the consultation or this is obviously load bearing.

I want to remove a wall that currently creates a 10’x3’ closet at the end of the kitchen. Reclaiming the space will give me room for a distinct dining area. It’s technically only 30 sq ft, but ultimately gives me about 100 sq ft more in functional space by letting me use space more efficiently. A big deal in a 800 sq ft condo

It doesn’t look like it’s load bearing in the attached building plan, but this is a basement/garden level condo in a three story 1920 brownstone. I do not have plans for other floors. The closet sits under the stone stairs in the main building vestibule. The wall runs parallel to the risers, and I think it sits right under the top step. That’s the only that gives be pause - is this wall likely bearing any of the load from the stairs?

Editing to add info: the wall is plaster and lathe over studs. The void below the closet/kitchen is a finished storage/crawl space. I’m adding a photo of the building entrance - not the best quality, but you can see the entry stairs, vestibule/landing, and more stairs. The landing sits above the crawl space in the building plan, and the second run of stairs starts above the back wall of the closet (top/front wall of crawl space).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is that wall made of? Drywall over studs? Plaster and lathe over studs? Bricks? Concrete?

Comment: "The closet sits under the stone stairs in the main building vestibule." Where is the footing of this stair in relation to this layout?

Comment: And which way do the ceiling joists run (I'm assuming there's no storey below this one)?